# PHP 'strpos($string, $value !== false)' Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, arrays, magento, strpos

I'm very new to PHP so I could be possibly overlooking something simple here.

A quick overview of what my script does:

- Interprest a CSV file and stores each row as an array (`$line`).
- Loops through the array `$line` and stores the results of the specified key as a a string (`$csv_product_list`) if the array is not empty.
- Retrieves a list of product SKU's from a Magento database and stores them as an array (`$sku`).

I am then attempting to loop through the `$sku` array whilst checking if the value of `$sku` exists within the string `$csv_product_list`. The problem is that I am receiving the same results even if the value **does** exist within the string `$csv_product_list`. For this validation I am using:

```
if (strpos($csv_product_list, $sku[$s] !== false)) {
    echo '<b>', $sku[$s], '</b> does exist within <b>$csv_product_list</b><br>';
} else {
    echo '<b>', $sku[$s], '</b> does not exist within <b>$csv_product_list</b><br>';
}
```

In the screenshot below, I have output the value of `$csv_product_list` and below that line are the loop results for two of the values of `$sku`.

[image]

As you can see, **CB853** is resulting that it does not exist within `$csv_product_list` despite the result above showing that it does.

Please note that **CB967** does not exist within `$csv_product_list`, so the results should be different from each other when this script is working correctly.

Please could anybody offer insight as to what is wrong here? My full code is included below for any clarification required. Thank you very much in advance for your time.

```
<?php
/** GLOBAL VARIABLES (START) */
    $client = new SoapClient('***'); // Magento API URL.
    $session_id = $client->login('***', '***'); // Standard API 'User Name' and 'API Key'. 
/** GLOBAL VARIABLES (END) **/

/** CSV (START) */
    $csv = array(); // ?
    $line = array(); // ?
    // ?
    if (FALSE !== $handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) {
        while (FALSE !== $row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $csv[] = $row;
        }
    }
    // ?
    foreach (array_slice($csv, 1) as $row) {
        $new_row = array();
        for ($i = 0, $c = count($csv[0]); $i < $c; ++$i) {
            $new_row[$csv[0][$i]] = $row[$i]; 
        }
        $line[] = $new_row;
    }
/** CSV (END) */

/** CSV SKU CONVERSION (START) */
    $csv_product_list = ''; // Create $csv_product_list variable before results of the loop are added.

    // Loop through each CSV row and assign the results to $csv_product_list.
    foreach ($line as $iLineNumber => $data_line) {
        $data_line_without_change = $data_line;

        if (!empty($data_line['Product SKU'])) {
                $csv_product_list .= $data_line['Product SKU'] . ' ';
        }
    }
/** CSV SKU CONVERSION (END) */

/** ZOEY PRODUCTS (START) */
    // Filter for where the 'FMA Stock' attribute is set to 'Yes'.
    $fma_stock_filter = array('complex_filter'=>
        array(
            array('key'=>'fma_stock', 'value'=>array('key' =>'eq', 'value' => 'Yes')),
        ),
    );
    // Retrieve list of products using the filter and assign the result to $zoey_product_list.
    $zoey_product_list = $client->catalogProductList($session_id, $fma_stock_filter);

    // Convert the result from $zoey_product_list into an array of SKU's as $sku.
    $sku = [];
    foreach ($zoey_product_list as $item) {
        $sku[] = $item->sku;
    }
/** ZOEY PRODUCTS (END) */

    echo 'The current contents of <b>$csv_product_list</b> are ', $csv_product_list, '<br><br>';

/*** DISABLE PRODUCTS (START) */
    for ($s = 0; $s < count($sku); $s++) {
        if (strpos($csv_product_list, $sku[$s] !== false)) {
            echo '<b>', $sku[$s], '</b> does exist within <b>$csv_product_list</b><br>';
        } else {
            echo '<b>', $sku[$s], '</b> does not exist within <b>$csv_product_list</b><br>';
        }
    }
/*** DISABLE PRODUCTS (END) */
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using it correctly:

```
if (strpos($csv_product_list, $sku[$s] !== false)) {
                                                ^ this is wrong
```

The result of `$sku[$s] !== false` is a boolean, `true` or `false`, so you are checking whether a boolean exists in `$csv_product_list`.

You need:

```
if (strpos($csv_product_list, $sku[$s]) !== false) {
                                      ^ here
```

Comment: I must get my eyes tested and my glasses replaced

Comment: Ugh, what a ridiculous mistake. I initially missed the `)` from the end of `false` so thought I had to put two of them there to fix the error. Thank you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The question title helped :-)

Comment: I was thinking Multi Byte Char set issues. Although that may well be worth mentioning anyway